# Converting Raster Values from Long Integer and Double Values to Short Integer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-conversion

In order to make my categorical raster data compatible with another model, I need to convert the values from Long Integer and Double to Short Integer. Is there a way to export or convert the files which would do this? I am using ArcMap.

Answer (score 1):

[Copy Raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm) with the `pixel type` property:

> Set the bit depth, or radiometric resolution, of the raster or mosaic
> dataset. If not defined, it will be taken from the first raster
> dataset.

```
    1_BIT —A 1-bit unsigned integer. The values can be 0 or 1.
    2_BIT —A 2-bit unsigned integer. The values supported can be from 0 to 3.
    4_BIT —A 4-bit unsigned integer. The values supported can be from 0 to 15.
    8_BIT_UNSIGNED —An unsigned 8-bit data type. The values supported can be from 0 to 255.
    8_BIT_SIGNED —A signed 8-bit data type. The values supported can be from -128 to 127.
    16_BIT_UNSIGNED —A 16-bit unsigned data type. The values can range from 0 to 65,535.
    16_BIT_SIGNED —A 16-bit signed data type. The values can range from -32,768 to 32,767.
    32_BIT_UNSIGNED —A 32-bit unsigned data type. The values can range from 0 to 4,294,967,295.
    32_BIT_SIGNED —A 32-bit signed data type. The values can range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
    32_BIT_FLOAT —A 32-bit data type supporting decimals.
    64_BIT —A 64-bit data type supporting decimals.
```

Comment: I've tried this but the VALUE field is still labeled as Long in properties. Am I missing something?